# MS Access 2007; extracting data from a user refined subform

Tags: ms-access, extract, subform

Looked everywhere for help on this; I can't believe that there's no way it can be solved:

Scenario:  I have an unbound subform that displays data in a datasheet.  The user selects a report to display from a combo box and a query is generated on the fly then displayed in the subform.  The user may then export the report (from the querydef) to an xlsx format file for distribution to colleagues.  All works well.

However, the user also refines the data in the datasheet, selecting and sorting using the column controls.  The question is:  how do I export the refined data?

I'd be very grateful for any help.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All the selecting and sorting of the datasheet is stored in the me.filter property of the subform.

So you take the filter and hand it over to the report. You can use the filter just like a normal WHERE-clause of a SQL query.

[the name of the SubForm container control in the host form].Form.Filter = the where clause

**EDIT:** Here is some code that you use in the **main form** preferrably in the procedure that kicks off the creation of the report:

```
dim strWHERE As String

strWHERE = Me.subform.Form.Filter
docmd.OpenReport "YourReport", , , strWHERE
```

Pls give us feedback if it works.

Comment: Thank you for your swift and considered response.  Unfortunately. I don't seem to have understood.  You say that the user's refinement is held in the subform's filter.  Therefore I can access it by referring to that filter: as in "  whereClause = me!MySubForm.Form.Filter "?  I'm getting this 2455 error: 'You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the property Filter'

Comment: Is it possible that when you tried you had *no filter* thus there cannot be a reference? In that case you need to check first if there is a filter.

Comment: Thanks @memerp, it's working now (I had to reload the form for the code to take affect).  It doesn't take any notice of ordering, but I can live with that.  Please accept my gratitude (and unbeknownst to them, the gratitude of one of the world's largest telecom companies)

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark this questions as answered ;)